# C# datatable take rows one at a time

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a datatable containing certain columns. I am able to display them in a repeater as a whole. However, what I want to do is to display the row, one by one. I want to create like a go next and show previous button. I did something like the following:

```
myDataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Take(1).CopyToDataTable();
```

This is giving me the first row. Now how can I use this concept to get the next row, (row 2), then row 3..... till row n. The rows being returned are different for different cases. It is an web application.

Comment: Is this a `WinForms` application?

Comment: If it's a web-application how are you persisting the `DataTable` between user requests (postbacks)?

Comment: @user3158622: you haven't understood my question. Postback was just another term for `user requests`. Are you using the `Session` to persist the table across postbacks?

Comment: Not using session, the skip worked for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a different row, you just need to `Skip` some:

```
myDataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Skip(n).Take(1).CopyToDataTable();
```

where `n` is how many rows you want to skip. So, for the second record `n` would be `1`.

I greatly disagree with the use of `CopyDataDataTable()`, but it would require a lot of knowledge of your code base to provide a better approach.

Comment: Agreed with the hesitation over `CopyToDataTable()`, seems like a code smell to me.

Answer (score 1):

I would select it from the database instead, however, use `Skip(n).Take(1)`:

```
var row3 = myDataTable.AsEnumerable().Skip(2).Take(1).CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 0):

Introduce the use of `.Skip()`:

```
myDataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Skip(0).Take(1).CopyToDataTable();
```

Now you can simply track which record the user is currently viewing, and update the value sent to the `.Skip()` method.  For example, if the user has pressed "next" 5 times, you've incremented the value 5 times:

```
myDataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Skip(5).Take(1).CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep a counter and use Skip(n-1).Take(1) for nth record.